# UILabel Text line set as square shape arrange iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel

I want to label Text arrange on square shape view format of label text line and label has some short word and some are Bigger size than other word of Label text so please see this Demo Image[Sqaure shape Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foDPR.png)

Comment: What u want to do is draw an image like this and then load the image on the button.

Comment: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/foDPR.png) @pRiva please click on this link to demo image

Comment: A label has only 1 font. Having multiple Fonts requires multiple Labels. Its not possible to make a UI like the demo with Labels. U can draw an image and add the image on a UIImage. If u mean u want to sort your labels you can use the Stack View and use some constraints. If thats what u want I can help you on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using NSAttributedString wish support multiple fonts and text sizes and use \n to return to the next line.

```
    NSDictionary *italicAttrs = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]};

    NSDictionary *defaultAttrs = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:16], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]};

    NSDictionary *arrowAttrs = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"AlNile-Bold" size:20], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor grayColor]};


    NSMutableAttributedString *labelText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

    NSAttributedString *from = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"From: " attributes:italicAttrs];

    NSAttributedString *content = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Me\n" attributes:defaultAttrs];

    NSAttributedString *arrow = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Ok" attributes:arrowAttrs];


    [labelText appendAttributedString:from];
    [labelText appendAttributedString:content];
    [labelText appendAttributedString:arrow];
```

Comment: yes its to make multiple fonts and text size using NSMutableAttributedString but. i want to make random font size and Font text size and not a fix text length its text length is Dynamic to suggest me